# How to format the output of a GROUP BY query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
require("config.php");
$result = mysql_query("select s_title, p_name, date from tbl_slist_info where publish='u' ORDER By date  ") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   { ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><?=$row['date']?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="g.php?title=<?=$row['s_title'] ?>"><?=$row['s_title'] ?></a></td>
   <td><a href="p.php?title=<?=$row['p_name'] ?>"><?=$row['p_name'] ?></a></td>
  </tr>
```

I want a mysql query such that I can diplay records according to dates. Suppose at 1-Jan I have 5 requests. On 2-Jan I have 4 request. IN this way

```
1-Jan
_____
A   type1
B   type1
C   type2
D   type1
E   type3

2-Jan
____
W    type4
X   type1
Y   type3
Z   type5
```

Comment: if you want to display results in that way you have to do it at application level.

Comment: SELECT date, name, type FROM table_name group by date;

Comment: if you use a GROUP-BY-clause, all the elements in the SELECT-clause need to be either in the GROUP-BY-list or be grouping functions. There are some versions of MySQL which accept the broken query, but they return more or less random values for the non grouped columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this at the database level:

```
SELECT concat(date, concat('\n__________\n', 
              group_concat(concat(concat(name, '\t'), type) SEPARATOR '\n')))
FROM table_name
GROUP BY date;
```

You probably should do it at the application level: When you iterate over the result set, check if the current date is different from the date of the previous row to detect group changes.

### Edit based on the added PHP code in the question

So something like this:

```
$lastDate = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['date'] != $lastDate) {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">'.htmlspecialchars($row['date']).'</td></tr>';
        $lastDate = $row['date'];
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="g.php?title='.urlencode($row['s_title']).'">'
              .htmlspecialchars($row['s_title']) .'</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="p.php?title='.urlencode($row['p_name']).'">'
              .htmlspecialchars($row['p_name']).'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: You have my +1. However date could have problems if it's the type datetime. Of course this is not functional under any circumstances, and should be done in the application and not MySQL. I was thinking about using cursor to resolve this, but rather as a challenge, not for the usefulness of the code. Something like CREATE TABLE #myAuxTable(myDay int, myMonth int)
Insert into #myAuxTbl
Select DISTINCT (day(myDate)) myDay, (month(myDate)) myMonth FROM MyTable Order by myMonth, myDay
declare @cursor cursor, @day int, @month int
set     @cursor = cursor for select myDay,myMonth from #myAuxTbl

Answer (score 0):

you can write a query, but the results will be TABULAR.

the results will repeat in columns.

Comment: Actually with my query date field is repeating again and again. that is <code>date, user, type</code>

Answer (score 0):

You'll might wish to do something like this:

```
$cookedData = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

  $cookedData[ $row['date'] ][] = $row;

}

foreach( $cookedData as $date => $relatedRecords ) {

   // emit $date here

   foreach( $relatedRecords as $oneRecord ) {

     // emit $oneRecord['s_title'] etc, here

   }
}
```